# Block email from submitting webforms

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a list of email addresses that I would like not be able to submit in webforms. I can't seem to find a setting for this? Is this currently possible or do I need to make a custom module to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably add a validation pattern to the email address and block a list of email addresses for submitting the form. Or you need to create a custom module.